# PHP Symfony 1.4: Task 'cc' is not defined

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Recently I've been working on Symfony project using a git repo. My problem is that when I try to clear the symfony's cache using `php symfony cc` or `php symfony cache:clear` i get message like:

```
Task "cc" is not defined.
```

Also, when I list all the possible actions using `php symfony` I can't find anything connected with clearing cache.

What's weird is that my friend using the same repo can clear his cache.

I'm using Fedora 16, Symfony's version is 1.4.17-DEV.

Tom

Comment: Not that it matters, but you should be using the latest stable, not the latest dev.

Comment: Where did you get your symfony version? https://github.com/symfony/symfony1 ? The latest version is 1.4.17.

Comment: Are both of you using exactly the same source & checkout point for symfony?

Answer (score 3):

Look in your .../symfony/lib/cache/ directory, may be empty, if so, recopy symfony files

Good luck